# import google contacts using OAuth 2.0 with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, google-contacts-api

Hi I try to wirte a web page for reading google contacts using OAuth in ASP.NET. On the Internet i found this page but is for php
[Import Contact with PHP](http://25labs.com/import-gmail-or-google-contacts-using-google-contacts-data-api-3-0-and-oauth-2-0-in-php/)
and  [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/552508/ASP-NET-Import-Gmail-Contacts) but the code don't use OAuth 2.0. 
But, out of curiosity, I can not even use Oauth?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look into socialauth-net component it uses OAuth 2.0, it can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/)

"With this library you can:

- Authenticate users with Facebook, Yahoo, Google, MSN, Twitter,
  MySpace and LinkedIn (more adding, soon!)
- Access profile of logged in user (Email, First name, Last name, Profile pic, DOB and more)*
- Get access to AccessToken of logged in User
- Consume REST API feeds of supported providers
- Import friend contacts of logged in user (Email, Profile URL and Name)*
- Easily extend this library to add any provider supporting OAuth1.0a, Oauth1.0+OpenID Hybrid or OAuth2.0 protocols
- Enable authentication on any existing quickly just be adding few DLLs and making some web.config changes
- Easily design UI for login screen or let SocialAuth.NET do it automatically for you"